# Different object fields in Typescript based on conditional type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, conditional-types

I want to write a function (eventual use is a React function component) in Typescript that takes a props object with a list of list of objects of any type. Assume the function should print a "key" for each, where if the object type has an id field then the id value is printed as the key, and if the object type doesn't have an id field, the key will be derived from an accessor function in the props object (pseudocode here with types omitted):

```js
function process(props: { items: ..., ...}) {
  props.items.forEach(item => {
    if (item.id) {
      console.log(`Key for ${item.id}`)
    } else {
      console.log(`Key for ${props.keyFunction(item)}`)
    }
  })
}

process({items: [{id: "1", name: "A"}, {id: "2", name: "B"}]})
process({items: ["A", "B"], keyFunction: (item) => item})
```

Ideally, I'd like the following:

1. Typescript should error if `keyFunction` is provided but the items already have an id
2. Typescript should error if the items don't have an id and `keyFunction` isn't provided
3. Typescript should know about keyFunction and id in the appropriate places inside the `process` function body (autocomplete should work)

Is there a way to write the types for this function so that all 3 of the above work?

Note: I understand that if these were parameters instead of values of a config object, I could use conditional function overloads, but because the actual use case for this is a React function component with props, that won't work here.

#### What I've tried

I've tried using a conditional type, which works at the callsite, but I can't figure out how to make Typescript know about `keyFunction` correctly [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIAUBOB7MBnAPAFQHxQF4psoIAPYCAOwBN0oBvKASxoC4p1glmqBzKAF8AUFCgB%20Ri0oBbdB2wBtALpDRUDg3VixzWfOIqA3Np0BreADEArlQDGwZiioAKPRBkKAlBy49%20JjpCJsIAZrYOTlRQYKh2EOhYeC6xaAZwiKgYOLhejOqpGAB07nJFMgCGYG6yhPhaQcyhUDUeJTR5DUFQds7oKAA2EEUDKHwuAAYZUKEoSFAAJAyl7YITXqaCpAPo0F1BvVT9QyNjk9Oz80uF6EUWIDb2js6tMl5rG0EiYoIbIsIAegBUAAygALFDWAY0KgAcmApCQqCQwlS8USLmW%20g4imW7CgACIAIwEgA0UCoFRkEA4BIAggTBOS8bSAExkilUmmEgBCjOUv1RcQS6ExpQMinpHIJfOU5Puj0izg4rzyBHwpUFgOB4Mh0MRyKFKHRoqxHglLMJJPJlOptIZTMYrDZHNt3Jl-PlVgizyoKtKao1skEgrRIrF2KgkoZ5I9Aq8QA):

```js
type KeyProps<T> = T extends { id: string }
  ? { items: T[] }
  : {
      items: T[];
      keyFunction(item: T): string;
    };

function process<T>(props: KeyProps<T>) {
  props.items.map(item => {
    if (item.id) {
      console.log(`Key for ${item.id}`)
    } else {
      console.log(`Key for ${props.keyFunction(item)}`)
    }
  })
}
```

I've also tried using a discriminated union, but I don't know how to provide a type constraint to only one branch of the union with a generic:

```js
type KeyProps<T> =
  | { type: "autokey", items: T[] } // How to provide that T should extend { id: string } here?
  | { type: "normal", items: T[], keyFunction(item: T): string }
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wg6OyW) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, please elaborate, preferably by [edit]ing your code example to demonstrate unsatisfied use cases.

Comment: Nice, yes that works great! Happy to accept the answer if you write it up!

Answer (score 0):

**Note** that this answer assumes that it isn't important that the two parameters are contained inside of a wrapper object.

> Ideally, I'd like the following:
>
> 1. Typescript should error if `keyFunction` is provided but the items already have an id
> 2. Typescript should error if the items don't have an id and `keyFunction` isn't provided
> 3. Typescript should know about keyFunction and id in the appropriate places inside the `process` function body (autocomplete should work)

Okey, requirement two (2) and three (3) can be solved by simply using function overloads and some cleverly selected default values *(you will see that we always call `keyFunction` and that this is actually a good idea)*.
However, requirement one (1) is quite tricky. We can easily infer the type of `items` using a generic `T`. Then using `T` we can derive a type `D` such that `D` does not contain any object types with a key of `id`. The tricky part is managing to both derive the base type `T` from `items` while also constraining the type of `items` to `D`.
The way I've done it is by using an intersection type `T[] & D[]` for the type of `items`. This will infer the base type `T` from elements in the `items` array, while also constraining the type of the elements in the `items` array.

```
interface ObjWithID {
    [k: string]: any;
    id: string;
}

type AnyWithoutID<T> = T extends { id: any } ? never : T;

function process(items: ObjWithID[]): void;
function process<T, D extends AnyWithoutID<T>>(items: T[] & D[], keyFunction: (value: T) => string): void;
function process(items: any[], keyFunction: (value: any) => string = ({id}) => id) {
  items.forEach(item => console.log(`Key for ${keyFunction(item)}`))
}

process([{id: "1", name: "A"}, {id: "2", name: "B"}])
process([{id: "1", name: "A"}, {id: "2", name: "B"}], (item) => item)
process([{ name: "A"}, { name: "B"}], (item) => item.name)
process(["A", "B"], (item) => item)
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWB1YYAWAkgCLIDeAUMtcgNoDWAXMgM5hSgDmAus3CAE8A3FRrAAJszYcQnEQF8KFMAIAOKAIKDcBAPYBXMCQA8AFQB8yALzJTyCAA9IIcS3LIJfQcnnIA-MggEABu0MjMpiIUMPogCGDAuiDIqlC6SCwsABR4EAC2LMwYOHhExLTcAJTMwboSIjFxCUkpaRksZgA0yKSOzq7IWgI6+AZGxGbm5jmQBREVyABkPRXd9BACAGKx8YkgzFnBcAA2+hARldaW0lzVyLX10TvNyanpEJkz+YXI-AKryHWW2eewOR1O51+gkuVmu7C41mQWTIEnkMMsEkulGouQKADoYLooABRRD4L55K7IBBJFi6Y4QPHHXScLIAAwA0htkISoMgACRkIHbJp7CmVeRsyqVCiKChvdpZWgoyTIABEAEY1d0QHA8pC1Ro1fJuirmGqAEzawJ6g0AIWNVXlbQ+2WVnnVWp1tvNRpN5A9lutuv15od8m43XFVNxMoVrqVZBtofVftNyftjqjsZjszxIYgcZdn1ohutaodkaROdhHlmMqAA)

**Note** that there is a rather annoying drawback when messing with the type system this much. The type errors end up quite cryptic. For instance `process([{id: "1", name: "A"}, {id: "2", name: "B"}], (item) => item)` will throw the error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.` for both `id` & `name` in both objects. These errors can be really annoying to debug, so make sure you absolutely need this kind of overload behavior before you commit to it fully.

Comment: Great answer! However, unfortunately it's necessary for them to be contained inside a wrapper object since the actual use case for this is React component props. From the question, "I understand that if these were parameters instead of values of a config object, I could use conditional function overloads, but because the actual use case for this is a React function component with props, that won't work here"